# Get real element's width in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, I have the next HTML markup (imitating my custom dropdown list inside a generic div):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectbox-body").css("width", $("#selectbox").width());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="outer-div">
 <label style="float: left; width: 100px; background-color: blue">LABEL</label>
 <div id="selectbox" style="background-color: pink">......</div>
 <div id="selectbox-body" style="position: absolute; height: 100px; background-color: red">12312313</div>
</div>
```

Or http://jsfiddle.net/sdkpkLds/ .

`#selectbox.width` equals to `#outer-div.width`, not `#outer-div.width - label.width`. How can I place `#selectbox-body` not under `label`?

Comment: Well, by floating the label, selectbox automatically takes 100% width, even if visually you may think not.

Comment: As `RumJeremy` already said, the `#selectbox` has `100%` width of the parent because it is floating ([updated fiddle with an outline to visualize it](http://jsfiddle.net/sdkpkLds/1/)). So either don't use float or you need to do something like `#selectbox.width - label.width`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the real, currently computed dimensions, you have two options:

1. getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("width")
2. element.getBoundingClientRect().width

The first is a CSS string with (px) unit, the second is a number.

(asking for the supposed CSS rule will only get you the "this is what the stylesheet/inline style says" information, which is very different from asking for the actual computed current dimensions)

Also note that `getComputedStyle` is a global function. Old tutorials might tell you to use `document.getDefaultView.getComputedStyle` or the like, which is no longer necessary.

Comment: Notice, that it's `getComputedStyle()`. Also good to mention, that this is a native DOM method in modern browsers, it is not included in jQuery (Though jQuery falls to this particular method under the hood when using `.css()`). `getComputedStyle(element,null).CSS_property_name` gives usually [more accurate information](http://jsfiddle.net/p5k2e6cf/), especially when a page is just loaded and no changes at all are made to CSS properties.

Comment: it is indeed and I can't believe I typed that wrong three times.

Comment: As I see getComputedStyle returns `#outer-div.width` and does not help me, or I wrong?

Comment: getBoundingClientRect - same here: width is `#outer-div.width`.

Comment: it returns the width of the element you check it for. If you use `var element = $('#outer-div')` then both getComputedStyle/getBoundingClientRect will give the width for that element. Remember that elements need to be as wide as their parents, or their children, and that overflow will *happily* mess things up.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, no, I use getComputedStyle of `#selectbox`, but on IE 10 its width the same as width of `#outer-div`, so it can't help me. Unfortunately, it looks like nothing is able to help me with the current HTML and I'm doomed to completely redesign it.